# JavaScript calculator program

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

So I'm trying to make a calculator for my job. Basically it is suppose to calculate someone's savings if they came with our firm. I have 3 working sections, but when I try to add another it doesn't work. I'll post a working section, and then the section that doesn't work.

WORKING:

```
<div id="VISABOX">
<h4 id="VISA">Visa</h4>
<input id="vVol" placeholder="Visa Volume..." type="text"><br>
<input id="vFees" placeholder="Visa Fees..." type="text"><br>

<button id="vCalc"> Calculate </button>
<p id="vEMDR" class="words">EMDR=<span id="vEMDRSPAN"></span></p>
<p id="vMonthly" class="words">Monthly Savings=<span id="vMonthlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="vYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="vYearlySpan"> </span></p>
<p id="vFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="vFiveSpan"> </span></p>
</div>

document.getElementById("vCalc").onclick=function(){

        var visaVol=document.getElementById("vVol").value;
        var visaFees=document.getElementById("vFees").value;
        var visaEMDR;
        visaEMDR=visaFees/visaVol*100;

        var visaMonthly=visaFees-(visaVol*.0171);
        var visaYearly=visaMonthly*12;
        var visaFive=visaYearly*5;

        document.getElementById("vMonthlySpan").innerHTML=" "+visaMonthly+"$";
        document.getElementById("vYearlySpan").innerHTML=" "+visaYearly+"$";
        document.getElementById("vFiveSpan").innerHTML=" "+visaFive+"$";
        document.getElementById("vEMDRSPAN").innerHTML=" "+visaEMDR+"%";

    }
```

NOT WORKING (also stops other buttons from working too):

```
<div id="OCBOX">
<h4 id="OCTitle">Other Charges</h4>
<input id="otherCharges" placeholder="Total Other Charges..." type="text"><br>
<input id="ourCharges" placeholder="Our Charges..." type="text"><br>

<button id="ocCalc"> Calculate </button>
<p id="ocMonthly" class="words">Monthly Savings=<span id="ocMonthlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="ocYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="ocYearlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="ocFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="ovFiveSpan"> </span></p>
</div>

document.getElementById("ocCalc").onclick=function(){

    var otherFees=document.getElementById("otherCharges").value;
    var ourFees=document.getElementById("ourCharges").value;

    var ocMonthlySav=otherFees-ourFees;
    var ocYearlySav=ocMonthlySav*12;
    var ocFiveSav=ocYearlySav*5;

    document.getElementById("ocMonthlySpan").innerHTML=" "+ocMonthlySav+"$";
    document.getElementById("ocYearlySpan").innerHTML=" "+ocYearlySav+"$";
    document.getElementById("ocFiveSpan").innerHTML=" "+ocFiveSav+"$";

}
```

I have NO idea what is happening... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: JavaScript is in the correct 
tags, I just didn't put them in the post.

Comment: Any error in `console` ? Have wrapped it in `script` tag ?

Comment: Also remember `.value` is always a string.

Comment: sorry, i edited it to put that i have it in the correct script tag. it's only when i add the second part that the whole thing stops working. I have 3 similar sections that have inputs and buttons that all work. just this one seems to crash it.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in this line:

```
 <p id="ocFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="ovFiveSpan"> </span></p>                                 <!-- =====oc not ov======^-->
```

o**c**FiveSpan not o**v**FiveSpan

Also, it's important to wrap your JavaScript in a `<script>` tag.

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WorxNo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="OCBOX">
    <h4 id="OCTitle">Other Charges</h4>
    <input id="otherCharges" placeholder="Total Other Charges..." type="text">
    <br>
    <input id="ourCharges" placeholder="Our Charges..." type="text">
    <br>

    <button id="ocCalc">Calculate</button>
    <p id="ocMonthly" class="words">Monthly Savings=<span id="ocMonthlySpan"></span>
    </p>
    <p id="ocYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="ocYearlySpan"></span>
    </p>
    <p id="ocFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="ocFiveSpan"> </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("ocCalc").onclick = function() {

      var otherFees = document.getElementById("otherCharges").value;
      var ourFees = document.getElementById("ourCharges").value;

      var ocMonthlySav = otherFees - ourFees;
      var ocYearlySav = ocMonthlySav * 12;
      var ocFiveSav = ocYearlySav * 5;

      document.getElementById("ocMonthlySpan").innerHTML = " " + ocMonthlySav + "$";
      document.getElementById("ocYearlySpan").innerHTML = " " + ocYearlySav + "$";
      document.getElementById("ocFiveSpan").innerHTML = " " + ocFiveSav + "$";

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```